# CSS is not getting updated in GXT textarea

Tags: java, html, css, gwt, gxt

I have a text area where I need to use one CSS onClick and another CSS onBlur. But it is not getting updated onBlur. Can you please help me ?

```
final TextArea textarea = new TextArea();
textarea.addBlurHandler(new BlurHandler() {

    @Override
    public void onBlur(BlurEvent event) {
        textarea.addStyleName("gxtTextAreaTransparentBackground");
    }
});

textarea.addDomHandler(new ClickHandler() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
        textarea.addStyleName("gxtTextAreaDefaultBackground");
    }
}, ClickEvent.getType());
```

And my CSS code is below,

```
.gxtTextAreaTransparentBackground * {
   background: red !important;
   border: 0 none !important;
   outline: none !important;
}

.gxtTextAreaDefaultBackground * {
   background: white !important;
   order: 1 none !important;
}
```

Comment: Hmm.. should work. Tried `setStyleName` as well ?

Comment: Not related to the question, but just a general note, you should avoid using `!important` whenever you can. So if it's not necessary to have those in, you should remove them.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, that in case the text area is focused, you want to change the styling, you can use `addBlurHandler` and `addFocusHandler`.

Also, I think, your problem is, that you do not remove the other style.

Something like that should work:

```
final TextArea textarea = new TextArea();

textarea.addBlurHandler(new BlurHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onBlur(BlurEvent event) {
        textarea.addStyleName("gxtTextAreaTransparentBackground");
        textarea.removeStyleName("gxtTextAreaDefaultBackground");
    }
});

textarea.addFocusHandler(new FocusEvent() {
    @Override
    public void onFocus(FocusEvent event) {
        textarea.addStyleName("gxtTextAreaDefaultBackground");
        textarea.removeStyleName("gxtTextAreaTransparentBackground");
    }
 });
```

Hope that helps.